# Is this constraint convex?

Tags: real-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem where the following constraint causes `DCP Rule Error`.

$$e^{x_n} \leq B \log _2\left(1+\frac{e^{\rho_n} g_n^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} e^{\rho_i} g_i^2+\sigma^2}\right)$$

Assuming that $\rho_n$ and $x_n$ are among the decision variables and $B$,  $\sigma$ and $g$  are constant. Is this constraint convex?

I tried to write the Python code of the optimization problem using the cvxpy library and the mosek solver, but the above clause causes a `DCP Rule Error`.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. This seems to be a nontrivial problem, which appears to have arisen in some (applied?) research.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the constraint as
$$x_n \le f_n(\rho_1,\dots,\rho_n):=\ln\Big(B\log_2\Big(1+\frac{e^{\rho_n} g_n^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} e^{\rho_i} g_i^2+\sigma^2}\Big)\Big).$$

The problem is then to prove the concavity of $f_n$. This seems to be a challenging problem.

We can do it for $n=2$. Indeed, in this case the problem reduces to showing that the function $f$ given by
$$f(r,s):=\ln\ln\Big(1+\frac{ae^s}{b+e^r}\Big)$$
is concave for any real $a,b>0$.
We have
$$\partial_s^2 f(r,s)
=\frac{a v (b+u)}{(b+u+a v)^2 \ln ^2\Big(1+\frac{a v}{b+u}\Big)}
\Big(\frac{a v}{b+u}-\ln \Big(\frac{a v}{b+u}+1\Big)\Big) <0 
$$
and
$$\partial_r^2 f(r,s)\,\partial_s^2 f(r,s)-\partial_r \partial_s  f(r,s)^2 =\\ 
\frac{a^2 u v^2 \big(b (a v+u)+b^2\big)}{(b+u) (a v+b+u)^4 \ln ^3(\frac{a v}{b+u}+1\Big)}
\Big(\frac{a v}{b+u}-\ln \Big(\frac{a v}{b+u}+1\Big)\Big)>0,$$
where $u:=e^r$ and $v:=e^s$.
So, $f$ is concave.